# Job ads: nameless numbered users in "Meet our team"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

It's kind of funny in a dystopian way, but are the job ads expected to show those?

[image: Meet our team: user9407268, user9389370, user9410155]

Comment: This is a problem the company created for themselves. Users are added to the team manually, and their team members are all lacking a decent Display Name.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/eroad

Comment: I am a free man...wait, no, I'm Employee # 9407268.

Comment: Wow, user9389370 seems like a great future colleague!

Comment: @teh4kman sorry I can't deal with names ending in 70... not since employee 4525470... now 9410155 looks like a real team player though!

Comment: Not sure about user9389370--there's just something vaguely sinister about that name.

Comment: That is truly funny

Comment: Even when you settle on a display name, there's still that one guy who insists on calling you user24601

Comment: E road, Ero ad, Er o ad...o_O

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, those ads will show a random selection of the team members the company has added to their company page. Those members are added manually.

In this case, the company has added a series of team members with standard display names, see https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/eroad. Only three accounts there have actually set a profile picture and name, the rest are 1 point accounts with no activity (all created on the same day, in a short amount of time).

In other words, this is working as designed, but not every company seems to fully understand what it means to add team members to their page that are otherwise anonymous and not even active on the site.

Comment: You might consider not allowing accounts without proper names to ever be selected for display.

Comment: "...will show a random selection..." Why a random selection and not the ones with the highest rep or picture and name? That might have helped here.

Comment: Not every smart team member has a high score, I'd still want to see whom I would be working with. Even a single answer can be a gem! And there are plenty of high-rep smart people on the site with the standard display name and avatar, filtering on that criteria would not be helpful.

Comment: maybe a descending sort by activity rather reputation

Comment: @MartijnPieters, But, it would be possible to remove from selection those users with no posts on SE, a standard "user*" name, and no self-entered public profile information (i.e the ones which contain *no* beneficial information). Sure, we might want to see the user with a single post, but there's no use in seeing users which are literally nothing other than "placehoder".

Comment: I think it's fine as is. If the company has to add stackoverflow users manually to their company, then I think it's fair that it's on them to make sure a display name / profile pic standard is in place. They're only making themselves look silly...

Comment: @Makyen: can I emphasise again that the selection is manual? I don't see any point in restricting this. If the company wants to put anonymous 1-point accounts on their team list, then that's their choice.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Yes, It's the company's choice. But It's SE's responsibility to educate them about the effects of their choice, and to make sure they actually want that choice, knowing the effects. It's SE's responsibility both from a duty to their client to do things to prevent them from misinformed actions which make them (and SE's service) look bad and from the point of view that SE makes more money when there isn't confusion resulting in fewer applicants and/or looking bad to those applicants. The education could be done many ways (e.g. a popup, a checkbox enabling putting those in, etc).

Comment: If those were added manually by the employer, this is great. It indicates that the employer is clueless. Valuable to know.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "They are a member of the team" and "I want to advertise using them as members of the team" are separate things.  The first implying the second is **not clear**.

Comment: @Yakk: I have no access to the company job advertising UI, I don't know what wording is used.